# rust quick-xml can't parse tags with colon using serde

Tags: xml, rust, serde

I have xml like this:

```
<item>
<title>Украина обвинила Германию в блокировании поставок оружия</title>
<link>https://www.rbc.ru/politics/12/12/2021/61b63a579a79477b9d2c5229</link>
<pubDate>Sun, 12 Dec 2021 22:21:11 +0300</pubDate>
<description>Министр обороны страны добавил, что из-за этого Киев будет пытаться приобрести оружие через сделки с США, Британией, Литвой и Францией</description>
<category>Политика</category>
<author>Евгения Воропаева, Артем Филипенок</author>
<guid isPermaLink="false">rssexport.rbc.ru::61b63a579a79477b9d2c5229</guid>
<rbc_news:pdalink>https://www.rbc.ru/politics/12/12/2021/61b63a579a79477b9d2c5229</rbc_news:pdalink>
<rbc_news:full-text>Германия блокирует поставки оружия Украине через агентство НАТО по обеспечению и закупкам, заявил газете Financial Times украинский министр обороны Алексей Резников. «Они (Германия) продолжают строить газопровод «Северный поток-2» и блокируют [поставки] оборонительных вооружений», — сказал Резников. По его словам, в ноябре Берлин наложил вето на покупку Украиной антиснайперских систем. Министр обороны добавил, что Украина будет пытаться приобрести оружие через двусторонние соглашения с США, Великобританией, Литвой и Францией. По словам Резникова, он провел переговоры о покупке оборонительных вооружений с Соединенными Штатами и другими западными странами и «оптимистично настроен» на этот счет. Но глава минобороны заявил, что не уверен, сможет ли страна получить необходимую военную технику до предполагаемого вторжения России на Украины. Резников подчеркнул, что западные страны не должны бояться решительных мер против России. «Стратегия непровоцирования России неэффективна и никогда не будет эффективной», — заявил он. 11 декабря посол Украины в Германии Андрей Мельник в интервью изданию zn.ua предупредил, что кабинет нового канцлера Олафа Шольца «вряд ли изменит отношение» к предоставлению оружия Украине. «Это очень разочаровывает, поскольку для нас именно сейчас наступил момент истины, пришло время понять — кто является настоящим другом не только на словах, но и на деле», — посетовал дипломат. Как ранее сообщала Frankfurter Allgemeine Zeitung, прежнее немецкое правительство не захотело поставлять Украине системы ПВО, части противокорабельных ракет, а также корветы. Издание утверждало, что против этого выступил министр иностранных дел Хайко Маас. Украинские военные за последние два месяца не раз утверждали, что Россия готовится к вторжению в их страну. Владимир Путин, комментируя обсуждение возможного нападения, заявил, что такие же разговоры велись весной, однако пока то, чего все опасались, не произошло. «Дело не в том, чтобы вводить войска или не вводить, воевать или не воевать, а в том, чтобы наладить отношения по созданию более справедливого, устойчивого развития и учета интересов по безопасности всех участников международной деятельности», — подчеркивал Путин.</rbc_news:full-text>
<rbc_news:anons>Министр обороны страны добавил, что из-за этого Киев будет пытаться приобрести оружие через сделки с США, Британией, Литвой и Францией</rbc_news:anons>
<rbc_news:news_id>61b63a579a79477b9d2c5229</rbc_news:news_id>
<rbc_news:tag>Украина</rbc_news:tag>
<rbc_news:tag>поставки оружия</rbc_news:tag>
<rbc_news:tag>Германия</rbc_news:tag>
<rbc_news:type>article</rbc_news:type>
<rbc_news:newsline>politics</rbc_news:newsline>
<rbc_news:newsDate_timestamp>1639336871</rbc_news:newsDate_timestamp>
<rbc_news:newsModifDate>Sun, 12 Dec 2021 22:21:12 +0300</rbc_news:newsModifDate>
<enclosure url="https://s0.rbk.ru/v6_top_pics/media/img/0/33/756393361976330.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="0"/>
</item>
```

And I using quick_xml with serde to parse this.

My structures:

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, PartialEq)]
pub struct Rss<T: Default + RssItem> {
  pub channel: Channel<T>
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, PartialEq)]
pub struct Channel<T: Default + RssItem> {
  #[serde(rename = "item", default)]
  pub items: Vec<T>
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, PartialEq)]
pub struct RbcItem {
  #[serde(rename = "rbc_news:news_id", default)]
  pub document_id: String,
  pub title: String,
  #[serde(rename = "pubDate", default)]
  pub publication_date: String,
  pub description: String,
  #[serde(rename = "rbc_news:full-text", default)]
  pub full_text: String
}
```

I use from_str function to parse:

```
let rss: Rss<RbcItem> = from_str(xml).expect("Error happened when parsing RBC rss");
```

But tags with colons doesnt parsed and they are blank.

```
RbcItem {
    document_id: "",
    title: "Как выглядели торнадо в США и что оставила после себя стихия",
    publication_date: "Sun, 12 Dec 2021 16:44:36 +0300",
    description: "На юго-восток страны обрушились торнадо. Больше всего пострадал штат Кентукки: разрушения зафиксированы в 12 его округах, погибли не менее 70 человек. Стихия затронула штаты Теннесси, Иллинойс, Миссури, Арканзас и Миссисипи",
    full_text: "",
}
```

Can some help with this, please, because I didnt found solution in issues or other topics in SO

Maybe I should leave issue on GitHub but i'm not sure

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed. It is missing XML namespace `xmlns:rbc_news` declaration inside the XML itself.

Comment: I didnt copy all xml, but it have xmlns:rbc_news in root node:

`<rss xmlns:rbc_news="http://www.rbc.ru" version="2.0"><channel><item></item></channel></rss>`
full rss can see [here](https://rssexport.rbc.ru/rbcnews/news/30/full.rss)

Comment: Should i prosess this namespace somehow?